# import schedule error [Python] after pip install

Tags: python, schedule

When I run `import schedule`   I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'`

I already did a pip install for `schedule`
FYI: I'm using: Python 3.85 venv

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple versions of Python installed and Pip is installing on that older version?

On Windows, search "Edit the system environment variables" and click on the "Environment Variables..." button. On the new window, search for the "Path" entry inside the "System variables" section and click on "Edit...".

[image]

Inside, click on "New" and add your Python 3.8 installation folder and Script folder like below. Be sure to click to each one of them and on "Move Up" till they get to top.

[image]